# Using a C++ DLL in C# when signature includes BYTE**

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke

I am working on a C# project, and am wrapping a C++ DLL for use in the project.  I have captured this behaviour in a test project, with function calls renamed to protect the innocent.

Everything seems fine, except for one type of function that I am having a hard time understanding.  The signature for that function in the DLL header is:

```
int32_t DoTheWork(BYTE **dest, BYTE *Src, int32_t szSrc);
```

My wrapper receives the Src byte array with no problem (easily tested since this is just a char string).  The return dest paramater is not quite so simple.

I have tried different ways to pass the dest parameter from C# to the wrapped function, but when I receive it back, either the dest byte array in C# has a length of 1 (instead of the expected 32) bytes, or the return crashes.  The instance I have below is a crash.  I need to understand how to pass a byte array as reference, copy results into that byte array, and return it with the full complement of bytes without crashing.  I have spent more than a day on this looking online and making changes to code, but am still not getting it to work correctly.

Also, would it be better for me to just take the pointer created in the C++ DLL all the way up into the C# calling function, instead of copying the values into the C# byte array in my C++ wrapper?  If so, how do I correctly go about cleaning up that memory inside of C#?

I am using VS2010 on Win8.  Here's my code:

** OriginalCPPClass.h for OriginalCPPDll.dll

```
class OriginalCPPClass {
public:
    OriginalCPPDLLClass();
    virtual ~OriginalCPPDLLClass();
    int32_t DoTheWork(BYTE **dest, BYTE *Src, int32_t szSrc);
};
```

** WrapperDLL.cpp (no accompanying .h file)

```
#include "CytoCrypto.h"

extern "C"
{

#define WRAPPERCLASS_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

WRAPPERCLASS_EXPORT OriginalCPPClass* Wrap_Create()
{
    return new OriginalCPPClass();
}

WRAPPERCLASS_EXPORT void Wrap_Destroy(OriginalCPPClass* pObj)
{
    delete pObj;
}

WRAPPERCLASS_EXPORT int32_t __cdecl Wrap_DoTheWork(OriginalCPPClass* pObj, BYTE **pDest, BYTE *pSrc, int32_t szSrc)
{
    BYTE *result = NULL;
    int32_t sz = pObj->DoTheWork(&result, pSrc, szSrc);
    *(result+sz) = '\0';
    if (sz > 0)
    {
        memcpy(pDest, result, sz );
    }
    return (sz >= 0) ? sz : 0;
}

}
```

** Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("OriginalCPPDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern IntPtr Wrap_Create();

        [DllImport("OriginalCPPDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void Wrap_Destroy(IntPtr pObj);

        [DllImport("OriginalCPPDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern Int32 Wrap_DoTheWork(IntPtr pObj, out IntPtr pDest, byte[] src, Int32 szSrc);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string src = "this is the source string";
            IntPtr pnt = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1000);
            byte[] bytearray = new byte[1000];
            byte[] srcBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(src);
            Int32 szSrc = srcBytes.Length;

            IntPtr obj = Wrap_Create();
            Int32 size = Wrap_DoTheWork(obj, out pnt, srcBytes, szSrc);
            Marshal.Copy(pnt, bytearray, 0, size);
            Wrap_Destroy(obj);

            Marshal.Copy(pnt, bytearray, 0, size);
        }
    }
}
```

Error dialog says:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: `BYTE **dest` in this case is a pointer to a byte array. The callee is responsible for allocating the array, and returns the address of that array to the caller. This wants to be `out IntPtr` in your C# code. You'll then use the `Marshal` class to copy from that pointer to a C# array. The unmanaged code will need to export a deallocator too.

Comment: This function is very hard to call reliably, it wants to return an array but there is no guidance how you are supposed to release the memory for the array.  If you are not supposed to release it then writing into the buffer is very risky.  And you didn't wrap it correctly, pDest needs to be BYTE* so the caller can pass a buffer to be filled.  And you need an extra argument that says how big the buffer is so you can't write beyond it and corrupt memory.  Talk to the programmer that wrote OriginalCPPClass, he needs to do a better job or provide guidance.

Comment: So then I need to do an out IntPtr, Marshal.Copy it to the bytearray variable, and make a call back to the C++ wrapper to do the delete?  I'll try that again.  I had tried that before, but did the BYTE* thing, rather than BYTE**.  That may be the problem since it makes sense that C# doesn't know about that type of construct.  Thanks.  I may end up with a crash from that, which is what I believe I remember from the last time I tried that way of doing it, but changing the signature to BYTE* might help.

Comment: I have it seeming to work now, but I am not getting the correct values back on the C# side.  I have put in a loop in my wrapper function to show me the unsigned char (cast as uint) values for the string I should be getting back.  It doesn't show a lot of repetition.  When I look at the byte array that I get back, it's a fully repetitive sequence of 4 values that don't look like anything in the wrapper function.  I'm wondering if I should be doing the Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1000) call for setting up the pnt pointer, but if I don't do that I crash on the way back out of the call.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found the right way to do what I needed.  Turns out that just passing a pre-sized byte array to collect the results is good (unfortunately have to pass a large enough buffer to handle the result, the length of which is unknown ahead of time but will never be greater than twice the original size).  Then in the wrapper class, I receive a newly allocated chunk of memory when I call the original C++ library, and copy the contents into my "BYTE* dest" parameter (no longer passed as BYTE**), and delete the chunk received from the library.  I just leave it up to automatic marshaling to handle the transfer of the array in both directions. Works perfectly, and the string of bytes I am getting back is proven to be correct.  Thanks for all the help.

Here's my final code:

** OriginalCPPClass.h for OriginalCPPDll.dll

```
class OriginalCPPClass {
public:
    OriginalCPPDLLClass();
    virtual ~OriginalCPPDLLClass();
    int32_t DoTheWork(BYTE **dest, BYTE *Src, int32_t szSrc);
};
```

** WrapperDLL.cpp

```
#include "CytoCrypto.h"

extern "C"
{

#define WRAPPERCLASS_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

WRAPPERCLASS_EXPORT OriginalCPPClass* Wrap_Create()
{
    return new OriginalCPPClass();
}

WRAPPERCLASS_EXPORT void Wrap_DestroyPtr(BYTE* ptr)
{
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, ptr);
}

WRAPPERCLASS_EXPORT int32_t __cdecl Wrap_DoTheWork(OriginalCPPClass* pObj, BYTE *pDest, BYTE *pSrc, int32_t szSrc)
{
    BYTE *result = NULL;
    int32_t sz = pObj->DoTheWork(&result, pSrc, szSrc);
    if (sz > 0)
    {
        memcpy(pDest, result, ret+1);
    }
    if (result)
        pObj->DestroyPtr(result);
    return (sz >= 0) ? sz : 0;
}

}
```

** Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("OriginalCPPDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern IntPtr Wrap_Create();

        [DllImport("OriginalCPPDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void Wrap_Destroy(IntPtr pObj);

        [DllImport("OriginalCPPDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern Int32 Wrap_DoTheWork(IntPtr pObj, byte[] dest, byte[] src, Int32 szSrc);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string srcStr = "this is the source string";

            byte[] resBytes = new byte[srcStr.Length*2];
            byte[] srcBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(srcStr);
            Int32 srcSize = srcBytes.Length;

            IntPtr obj = Wrap_Create();

            Int32 size = Wrap_DoTheWork(obj, resBytes, srcBytes, srcSize);

            Wrap_Destroy(obj);
        }
    }
}
```